# Encoding a comma with stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

Tags: objective-c

Why doesn't the comma get encoded? I was expecting it to be %2C.

```
(lldb) po [@"," stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:4]
(id) $24 = 0x0a8fbfd0 ,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @DayS, because comma is a legal URL character. However, if you would like to have control over which characters are escaped, look at `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()`.

```
NSString *toencode = @",";
NSString *result =
CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                          (__bridge CFTypeRef)toencode,
                                                          NULL,
                                                          CFSTR(","),
                                                          kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This method will only replace special characters which aren't valid in a URL. As the comma is a valid one, he'll stay like this.

Try with this string to check :

```
[@",éà /" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

To replace other characters like comma, you have to do it yourself...